# Access violation error during a printf

Tags: c, debugging, printf

I'm trying to use the printf function to print a string from a pointer passed in to the function.

```
printf("%s\n", strng[1]);
```

strng is passed in by the caller. It is a string with a space in front of it and I want to remove that white space. Thus I have the code below.

```
for(i=0; i<slength -1; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", strng[1]);
    tstr[i] = strng[i+1];
    printf("%s\n", tstr);
}
tstr[slength] = 0;
```

it keeps giving me a access violation error and I don't understand why. If I take the printf line out then I can run the code but the return string tstr always has an extra character at the end of it. The output looks like this.

```
  bp185080
  9
 bªM
 bpM
 bp1
 bp18─
 bp185
 bp1850K
 bp18508
 bp185080=::=::\
 bp185080=
```

how do I get rid of the white space and not have an extra character?

Comment: Can you please show the declaration of `strng`?

Comment: Why not just call strcpy?

Comment: strng is an input argument. so example of the input is " he939379"

Comment: There is a white space in front of the original string i'm tyring to remove

Comment: fixed. Index problems....

Answer (score 4):

You are basically trying to use a character as a pointer. Replace `strng[1]` with either `&strng[1]` or `strng + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop has a couple of problems with the printf's;

```
for(i=0; i<slength -1; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", strng[1]);   // Prints a character with a format of a string,
                                // you may want to use %c here instead to print
                                // the second char, or strng+1 to print the
                                // string starting with the second character.
    tstr[i] = strng[i+1];
    printf("%s\n", tstr);       // Prints tstr before terminated with \0, which
                                // is undefined behaviour, may very well crash.
}
tstr[slength] = 0;
```

It also seems that you're looping one iteration too little to handle the last character, you'll probably want to do `for(i=0; i<slength; i++)`.

Comment: Consider `tstr[i] = 0;`.  It deals with the abnormal case of slength < 0.